# Copy / paste dynamic named range from Excel to SAP with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to copy a dynamic (named) range of cells from Excel to SAP with the help of a VBA script (manually this would be done through a copy / paste from a clipboard ). The range of values from Excel need to be copied into the multiple selection window of SAP.
But unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve it.
This is where I get an error.

`Vendors = Sheets("vendors").Range("UniqueVendors").Value`

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

[image: FBL1N function in SAP for clipboard pasting]

Please see here below the code I'm using:

```
Public SapGuiAuto, WScript, msgcol
Public objGui  As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession

Sub SAPDownloadReport()

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)
Dim CompanyCode As String
Dim ClearingStartDate As Date
Dim ClearingEndDate As Date
Dim SAPLayout As String
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Vendors As Integer


CompanyCode = Sheets("report").Range("B2").Value
ClearingStartDate = Sheets("report").Range("B3").Value
ClearingEndDate = Sheets("report").Range("B4").Value
SAPLayout = Sheets("report").Range("B5").Value
FolderPath = Sheets("report").Range("B6").Value
Vendors = Sheets("vendors").Range("UniqueVendors").Value

'Insert your SAP Script here

session.FindById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nFBL1N"
session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_KD_LIFNR_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = Vendors
session.FindById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/radX_CLSEL").Select
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKD_BUKRS-LOW").Text = CompanyCode
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_AUGDT-LOW").SetFocus
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_AUGDT-LOW").caretPosition = 0
session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").focusDate = ClearingStartDate
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectionInterval = "20211001,20211001"
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_AUGDT-HIGH").SetFocus
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_AUGDT-HIGH").caretPosition = 0
session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").focusDate = ClearingEndDate
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectionInterval = "20211105,20211105"
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPA_VARI").Text = SAPLayout
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPA_VARI").SetFocus
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPA_VARI").caretPosition = 12
session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = FolderPath
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "EXPORT.XLSX"
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 5
session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press


MsgBox "Extraction done"

End Sub
```

(Maybe copying a Named Range isn't the solution maybe copying the Clipboard from Excel or something different is?)

Answer (score 2):

If the Excel data is in the clipboard with the .Copy command, it can be pasted into SAP as follows:

```
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_KD_LIFNR_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: @ceci and ScriptMan , thanks, this combination works :

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the SAP part but instead of copying you are trying to assign your range to an integer. Replace your "vendors = .." line with:

```
Sheets("vendors").Range("UniqueVendors").Copy
```

So no need to assign to anything.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately it only copies only a "0" value to SAP

Comment: When you manually paste after this code runs you have data? If yes, Your sap code is wrong.

Comment: yes, manually pasting works, but the sap code part also works when I use it like : session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").text = "400025641"  Maybe another solution?